# The namespace of a Coded UI Test Map (UIMap.uitest)? change

Tags: c#, automation, coded-ui-tests

Please refer to:
[The namespace of a Coded UI Test Map (UIMap.uitest)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499483/the-namespace-of-a-coded-ui-test-map-uimap-uitest?answertab=active#comment10886243_8733979)

Nick how could you solve this problem?

"Thanks for the tip. The default namespace was not really my issue. Apparently when using UIMaps the designer always creates an extra namespace level, named "Classes". Very annoying at start after doing some customizations. This is the rule - I experienced it now over time :-) - so now that I know, I can deal with it and it's a non-issue now. Case closed."

Please reply to inathalybv@gmail.com

Thanks

Comment: This is a question part. You can write these after Nick's comment which he can see. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: And looks like you wrote this as an answer in past.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23139624/447156 Don't do that.